# When to use Shell=True for Python subprocess module

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

It seems whenever I try to use Python's subprocess module, I find I still don't understand some things. Currently, I was trying to join 3 mp4 files from within a Python module.

When I tried

```
z ='MP4Box -cat test_0.mp4 -cat test_1.mp4 -cat test_2.mp4 -new test_012d.mp4'
subprocess.Popen(z,shell=True)
```

Everything worked.

When I tried

```
z = ['MP4Box', '-cat test_0.mp4', '-cat test_1.mp4', '-cat test_2.mp4', '-new test_012d.mp4']
subprocess.Popen(z,shell=False)
```

I got the following error:

```
Option -cat test_0.mp4 unknown. Please check usage
```

I thought that for `shell=False` I just needed to supply a list where the first element was the executable I wanted to run and each succeeding element was an argument to that executable. Am I mistaken in this belief, or is there a correct way to create the command I wanted to use?

Also, are there any rules for using `Shell=True` in subprocess.Popen? So far, all I really know(?) is "don't do it - you can expose your code to Shell injection attacks". Why does `Shell=False` avoid this problem? Is there ever an actual advantage to using 'Shell=True`?

Comment: try with [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) for correct tokenization of arg, as in the example in [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Comment: @Ami Tavory - Thanks, I think that does answer my question. But, to be certain I understand, when `shell=True`, the shell program will parse the cmd string. Because the shell program is meant to be very general, it will accept and execute a far larger variety of commands than I intended for what is likely meant to handle only a very specific command and its options. Use of `shell=False` and shlex limits the set of strings that will be executed to something closer to my specific use-case. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: @user1245262, ...basically, `shell=True` honors _all_ shell syntax, including things like command substitution; `shlex.split` honors quotes and spaces only -- not command substitutions, or command separators, or so forth. Honestly, I often think people recommend even `shlex.split` when it's not a good idea -- using it means that filenames that _contain_ quotes/spaces/etc can't be used without making trouble. Sticking with the default `shell=False` and providing an explicit list is the safest route.

Answer (score 16):

If shell is `True`, the specified command will be executed through the shell. This can be **useful if you are using Python primarily for the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want convenient access to other shell features** such as shell pipes, filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of `~` to a user’s home directory.

**When `shell=True` is dangerous?**

If we execute shell commands that might include **unsanitized input from an untrusted source**, it will make a program vulnerable to **shell injection**, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the **use of `shell=True` is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input**

Eg. (Taken from [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments))

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> filename = input("What file would you like to display?\n")
What file would you like to display?
non_existent; rm -rf / #
>>> call("cat " + filename, shell=True) # Uh-oh. This will end badly..
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to give every single argument as one element of a list:

```
z = ['MP4Box', '-cat', 'test_0.mp4', '-cat', 'test_1.mp4', '-cat', 'test_2.mp4', '-new', 'test_012d.mp4']
subprocess.Popen(z,shell=False)
```

This is normally what you want to do, because you don't need to escape especial characters of the shell in filenames.