# How do I pass inputs into another Python script's `sys.argv` list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, argv

I have a Python script I wrote to be called from the command line.  I am writing a GUI wrapper but do not want to change the main function.  In the GUI code, I am calling the script using `subprocess.run(['./executable.py', input])` but the input is not visible in `executable.py`'s `sys.argv` list.  How do I pass the input such that it would be visible to `sys.argv`?

Here is a test script I have saved as `test.py` (made it executable `chmod +x test.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# script to test using sys.argv with subprocess

import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

Here is what I get when calling this from the command line:

```
$> ./test.py input.txt
['./test.py', 'input.txt']
```

Here is what I get when calling this from within a python shell:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.run(['./test.py', 'input.txt'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> >>> print(output.stdout)
b"['./test.py']\n"
```

How do I get `input.txt` to show up in `sys.argv`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `shell=True` unless you absolutely know you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to do this is to simply remove `shell=True`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.run(['./test.py', 'input.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print(output.stdout)
b"['./test.py', 'input.txt']\n"
```

The other option is to combine the list of inputs into a single string:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.run('./test.py input.txt', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print(output.stdout)
b"['./test.py', 'input.txt']\n"
```

I am not completely sure why the original method (with a list of inputs and `shell=True` fails) fails.  Regardless, to avoid [running unintended commands/code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) it is best to avoid using `shell=True` ([note on when you should use `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30831028/3585557)).

Comment: It's better to remove the `shell=True` instead.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell `shell=True` is quite risky, for details have a look at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations