# How to pass arguments to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I want run a process called client.sh in gnome-terminal via python script and want to pass the arguments as input to execute it.  Below is my code

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import pexpect
process = subprocess.Popen('sudo gnome-terminal  -x ./client.sh', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
process.communicate(input = "1")
```

my intension is to send input as "1" to client.sh process.
But with above code my process[client.sh] didn't get any input.
How can i send inputs to my sub process process?.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: If you don't explain what the problem is, there's no reason why this question shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of the 3 thousand other "how do I start a subprocess" questions. Care to be more specific? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Popen.communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768290/understanding-popen-communicate)

Comment: i would like send input to the process. itried process.communicate as explained above . But it didnt work.

Comment: What does "it didn't work mean"? Did it throw an error? Did the process not get the input? What happened?

Comment: Process not get the input

Comment: try `process.communicate(input = b"1\n")` (with a linefeed)

Comment: also you may want to get hold of program output (get return value of `communicate`)

Comment: Hi Jean,  i tried process.communicate(input = b"1\n"). same result again. My process didn't get any input

Comment: have you tried with a simpler example? without `sudo`, a script that reads standard input using `read` ? that would be the place to start

Comment: with out sudo i couldn't even open the sub-process in gnome-terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the command with the argument:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo gnome-terminal  -x ./client.sh', '1'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)
```

Be carefull when using `shell=True`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30831028/8135079).

If you need to "emulate" an argument input, use:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo gnome-terminal  -x ./client.sh'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)
```

and then:

```
process.stdin.write("1" + "\n")
```

Comment: I tired as you suggest . Getting the below error if i make shell = False                                                                                       process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo gnome-terminal -x ./client.sh','1'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: see my edit. 
Also, try using the full path, i.e: `/home/foo/client.sh`